# How do I get the number of online players in a Minecraft server from outside the client?

Tags: java, mobile, minecraft-modding

I know that the Minecraft client can query the server for number of players and maximum players, even when the server properties has `enable-query` set to `false`, but how do I do this outside of the client? I am trying to implement this as part of a mobile (Android) app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually [quite well-detailed at this page](http://wiki.vg/Server_List_Ping). Please note that I am going to detail the common protocol introduced in version 1.7. Additionally, [a new protocol was introduced in 1.9pre4](http://wiki.vg/Query) that contains additional information not found in the previous protocol. Let me detail how to get the basic server information in 1.7+:

1. Send a "handshake" packet with the layout:

   - 0x00 (Packet ID)
   - 0x04 (Protocol Version)
   - Length of server address. [This is a VarInt](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding), which means that it has a variable length. The last bit of each byte that would normally indicate the sign instead indicates if the next byte is part of the VarInt.
   - Server address (Host Name or IP Address)
   - Server port (as a Short, Big-endian)
   - 0x01 (Next State)
2. Send a blank "Status Request" packet with the layout:

   - 0x00 (Packet ID)
3. Reading the response, you will get a JSON-encoded object with the following format:

   - Version

     1. Name
     2. Protocol
   - Players

     1. Max
     2. Online
     3. Sample
   - Description

     1. Text
   - Favicon

     1. Mime-type;encoding,

Since you are writing this for Android, I presume you are using Java. Luckily for you, there is already [an open-source Java project](https://gist.github.com/zh32/7190955) that details these steps already made for you. Even better, it shows proper use of VarInt when formatting your packets.